# Axios POST to Mailchimp API: HTTP Authentication not working

Tags: javascript, http-headers, axios, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to make an axios request to my mailchimp account. But it does not seem to be working. I cannot get it to authorize me - what am I doing wrong here? I have been following [this tutorial:](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) which says:

> There are 2 authentication methods for the API: HTTP Basic
>   authentication and OAuth2. The easiest way to authenticate is using
>   HTTP Basic authentication. Enter any string as your username and
>   supply your API Key as the password. Your HTTP client library should
>   have built-in support for Basic authentication, but here’s a quick
>   example that shows how to authenticate with the --user option in curl:

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/' \
--user 'anystring:<your_apikey>'
```

So I implemented:

```
axios.post('https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xad81287/members/', {
      auth:
        {
          url: 'https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0',
          user: 'blabla:11231h23123j14bhj1b23j12-us1' //this is my API key
        },
      firstName: 'Fred',
      lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

(I have changed the API things and list names here randomly)

Error I'm getting:

> OPTIONS https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/afafaf/members/
>   401 (Unauthorized) dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178 xhrAdapter @
>   xhr.js:12 dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59 Promise resolved
>   (async) request @ Axios.js:51 Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:71
>   https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/afafaf/members/: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Comment: Any solution? I can make it work fine in terminal and postman, etc. can't get it working with axios......

Comment: back end written in which language ?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
axios({
  method:'post',
  url: 'https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xad81287/members/',
    auth: {
      username: 'Fred', // anystring
      password: '11231h23123j14bhj1b23j12-us1' // Your API key
    }
}).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

It work for me.

For work with Mailchimp API from `localhost` (so that there is no CORS error) quit Google Crome and open it with this command:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```

Comment: I am at a complete loss as to why you think that would solve the cross-origin permissions problem.

Comment: Because today I was faced with this problem and this decision was the right one.